# A simple CMS that can be accessed from a command line script

Tags: linux, cms, command-line

For personal use, I'm looking for a content management system that can easily be accessed by scripts using standard Linux userland commands.  That can either be one that runs locally and uploads its results or one that runs on a server and is accessed over ssh. It only needs to be able to create a flat website and serve static pages plus images, PDFs and other static resources.

I've only been able to find [`simple-bash-cms`](https://github.com/rubickcz/simple-bash-cms), which looks like it might do the job, but hasn't been updated in a while.  Wondering if there are more popular tools available.

Comment: You seem to be interested in static site generators. We have a tag for them: [tag:static-site-generator].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried these myself but here are couple options you should consider:

- [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/)
- [BlazeBlogger](http://blaze.blackened.cz/)
- [DokuWiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/) - in case you are looking for KnowledgeBase sharing solution. Pages are stored in static files.

All of them are using flat files which makes it easy to automate deployment and management using command line. So they meet requirements listed. All of them are free so it is good reason to try them. I have personally used DokuWiki for changing content locally and upload them using shell scripts to remote server.

Comment: Do those products match the requirements listed? Why should they be considered (anything specific about them that lets you recommend them)? Please see [our answer guide](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) on what an answer should contain, and [edit] your post to better reflect that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: All of them are using flat files which makes it easy to automate deployment and management using command line. So yes, they meet requirements listed. Anything specific you noticed that does not match requirements listed?

Comment: Not me personally, Alex – I've just noticed those parts were completely missing. Not my area of experience, so I cannot tell specifics :) Thanks for your feedback, integrated that with your post. Be welcome to [edit] it again and add anything you might find useful in the context (e.g. pricing, license). I understand you cannot share personal experience – but if you picked up some "appraisal facts" (aka "good reasons to use exactly this one"), be welcome to add it :)